# How can I formulate this regex to avoid nesting or non-greedy matching?

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7, pcre, regex-greedy

I am developing a regex based filter for Drupal. This is the regex  `/[asciidoc]((.|\n)*)\[\/asciidoc]`. When it appears multiple times in the text all the all the instances of [asciidoc] and [/asciidoc] are matched by the first and last ones.

eg. In code a piece of code like

```
[asciidoc] here is some text to be filtered[/asciidoc]
a bit of text
[asciidoc]some text in a second block[/asciidoc]
```

`here is some text to be filtered` and `some text in a second block` are supposed to be processed by the filter but

```
here is some text to be filtered[/asciidoc]
a bit of text
[asciidoc]some text in a second block
```

gets matched between the first and last block markers. When I test in `regex101` the notes say the regex matches the code in the blocks in a `greedy` manner so it is a `non-greedy` regex which will not allow this kind of nesting of the blocks I need.

What should be the correct regex? I am not familiar with the regex lingo so may be using some of the terms wrongly.

Comment: This `(.|\n)` matches any character, this `*` is a greedy quantifier. You can _qualify_ all quantifier's to be non-greedy by placing a question mark `?` after it. Just a fyi, even the non-greedy version will match `"[asciidoc] here is some text to be filtered[asciidoc]
a bit of text
[asciidoc]some text in a second block[/asciidoc]`[/asciidoc][/asciidoc]", so don't blame it on the regex greedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work with `DOTALL` flag and a lazy quantifier:

```
$re = '~\[asciidoc](.*?)\[/asciidoc]~s'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3JbKI6/1)

If you want to use `/` as regex delimiter with no support of `DOTALL` flag (like Javascript) then use:

```
/\[asciidoc]([\s\S]*?)\[\/asciidoc]/
```

Comment: When I try it code like this - `preg_match($re, $foo, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);` only the first match ie `here is some text to be filtered` is captured in the array. The second `some text in a second block` is not. What could be the problem?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` to get all matches.